# gorilla/schema and mgo/bson.ObjectId

Tags: mgo, gorilla

Here's a bit of a chicken and egg problem.

In a HTML template, a form, bson.ObjectId needs to be rendered with `{{mytype.Id.Hex()}}`

e.g.

```
<form method="post">
<input name="id" value="{{mytype.Id.Hex()}}>
</form>
```

In Go when defining a struct that is supposed to be parsed by gorilla/schema

```
type MyType struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" schema:"id"`
}
```

when you call (from schema) `decoder.Decode(instance_of_mytype, r.PostForm)`
it "throws" an error: `schema: invalid path "id"` since the format is just the string respresentation of bson.ObjectId and not an actual bson.ObjectId.

I wonder what I could do except filling the fields manually (`r.FormValue()`) to make it work.

Should I create an issue with gorilla/schema or mgo or should I just do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might define your own string-based type which holds the hex representation of the value, and implement the [bson.Getter](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Getter) and [bson.Setter](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) interfaces on it. Gorilla will ignore these interfaces and use the string value, and bson will ignore the string value and use the interface.

Something along these lines (untested code):

```
type hexId string

func (id hexId) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
        return bson.ObjectIdHex(string(id)), nil
}

func (id *hexId) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
        var objId bson.ObjectId
        err := raw.Unmarshal(&objId)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        *id = hexId(objId.Hex())
        return nil
}
```